TypeError: GenerativeModel.generate_content() got an unexpected keyword argument 'model'
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import google.generativeai as genai
import pathlib

# Load the environment variables from the .env file
load_dotenv()

# Retrieve the Google API key from environment variables
GOOGLE_API_KEY = os.getenv('GOOGLE_API_KEY')

model = genai.GenerativeModel('gemini-1.5-flash')

my_picture = {
    'mime_type': 'image/png',
    'data': pathlib.Path('image2.png').read_bytes()
}
prompt = "Describe this image in detail"

response = model.generate_content(
    model="gemini-1.5-flash",
    content=[prompt, my_picture]
)
print(response.text)

I Keep getting the error that,
GenerativeModel.generate_content() got an unexpected keyword argument 'model' but I've tried many ways to solve it, just doesn't seem to work.
I've tried running this command : pip install --upgrade google.generativeai
And also this command: pip install --upgrade google-cloud-aiplatform
Still couldn't get any results.
Tried going the other way around with this code:
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import google.generativeai as genai
import pathlib
load_dotenv()

GOOGLE_API_KEY = os.getenv('GOOGLE_API_KEY')
genai.configure(api_key=GOOGLE_API_KEY)

def get_prompt_from_image(image_path, text_prompt):
    image_data = pathlib.Path(image_path).read_bytes()


    image_prompt = {
        'mime_type': 'image/png', 
        'data': image_data
    }


    model = genai.GenerativeModel('gemini-1.5-flash')

    response = model.generate_content(
        model="gemini-1.5-flash",
        content=[text_prompt, image_prompt]
    )

    return response.text

if __name__ == '__main__':
    image_path = 'path_to_your_image.png'  
    text_prompt = "Describe this image."
    prompt = get_prompt_from_image(image_path, text_prompt)
    print(f'Generated Prompt: {prompt}')

And still same error.

Just take model out from the call. generate_content() only accepts the content, by typing model.generate_content() you are already applying the method to your model, no need to specify it further

import os
import google.generativeai as genai

genai.configure(api_key=os.getenv('GEMINI_API_KEY'))

import PIL.Image

img = PIL.Image.open('sami.png')
model = genai.GenerativeModel('gemini-1.5-flash')
response = model.generate_content(["Please describe the image in detail.", img])
description = response.text

This was the right code,
